# Is the running time of this double loop O(n2^n) or O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

```
def sum_t(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, 2**(i)+1):
            total = total+1
```

I originally thought it was `O(n2^n)`. However, if you write it in sigma notation, it can be simplified to `2^n+1 - 2` or `2(2^n)-2`.

- If `n=1` then `total=2`
- If `n=2` then `total=6`
- If `n=3` then `total=14`
- etc.

Is it `O(n2^n)` or `O(2^n)`?

Answer (score 1):

1st loop:

When n = 1, `for i in range(1, n+1)` runs 1 time

When n = 2, `for i in range(1, n+1)` runs 2 times

When n = n, `for i in range(1, n+1)` runs n times

2nd loop (notice that i = n):

When n = 1, `for j in range(1, 2**(i)+1)` runs 2 times (or 2^1)

When n = 2, `for j in range(1, 2**(i)+1)` runs 4 times (or 2^2)

When n = 3, `for j in range(1, 2**(i)+1)` runs 8 times (or 2^3)

When n = n, `for j in range(1, 2**(i)+1)` runs 2^n times

The two loops together should take n*2^n time to finish. So BigO(n2^n)

The total calculation in the function does not affect BigO. It would if for example this was the function:

```
def sum_t(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, 2**(i+total)+1):
            total = total+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `range` in the inner loop increases exponentially, the last run of the inner loop dominates the running time. In fact, the running time of the last iteration exceeds the sum of the running time of all of the previous iterations. Therefore, we can write that the total running time is
 `< 2x` where `x` is the run time of the last iteration.

Which means that the big-O of the code is determined solely by the running time of the inner loop when the outer loop is on its last iteration. So the time complexity is `O(2^n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in terms of BigO ,But the tight upper bound is O(2^n)

for i=1  second loop runs - 2^1 times

for i=2  second loop runs  - 2^2 times

.....

for i= n  second loop runs -2^n times

The overall time complexity  is just sum of 2^1 + 2^2 + .... + 2^n 
This is in Geometric progression ,so sum of elements is  2(2^n-1) =  BigO(2^n)